# setInterval doesn’t work continuously and stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

The start is `01:59`. When I refresh the page, it becomes `01:58` and stops on that. It should become `01:59`, then `01:58`, then `01:57` etc.

```js
function timer() {
  let time = 119,
    minutes = Math.floor(time / 60),
    seconds = time % 60;
  
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  }
  else if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }
  
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds = seconds - 1;
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(SI);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

let SI = setInterval(() => {
  timer();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: FYI: Set Timeout is NOT accurate

Comment: `let time=119,` so why do you set the time on every interval back to 119?

Comment: Step through your code. Put a breakpoint on your `clearInterval` call and see if it gets called. Note that `seconds = seconds - 1;` makes `seconds` a number again, so the zero padding done above it is wasted...

Answer (score 0):

You are restting the `time` variable on each `time()` iteration.
Move the initialization outside the function.

Also, you've forgot to remove 1 second from the `time` variable after the function call `time--`;

```js
function timer() {
  
    let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60),
    seconds = time % 60;
  
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  }
  else if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }
  
  if (seconds > 0) {
    time--;
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(SI);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}


let time = 119;
let SI = setInterval(() => {
  timer();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: (1) Why I have to put `time--;` if the `seconds=seconds-1;` is already exists? I saw similar code like mine & it worked.
(2) Seconds when it reach 9 or lower it becomes without 0 in the first.

Comment: The `timer()` function uses the `time` variable to check the remaining time. You calculate the remaing seconds, and save those in the `seconds` variable. However, on the next function iteration, you are calculating the second again, using the `time` variable. Therefore you'll need to lower the `time` variable to calculate the remaining seconds.

Comment: One small bug to fix: it should be `if( time > 0 ) { time--; }`, or the timer display will never decrement the minute part

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Even I don't know how the minutes are running without a code for it O.o

```
let time=123;
function timer(){
    let minutes=Math.floor(time/60),
        seconds=time%60;
    /*if(minutes<10){
        minutes=`0${minutes}`;
    }if(seconds<10){
        seconds=`0${seconds}`;
    }*/
    if(time>0){
        time=time-1;
    }
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=`${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
setInterval(()=>{
    timer();
},1000);
```

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be `setInterval(timer,1000)` for the timer component.